# Discussion Board - SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, discussion-board

I am creating a Discussion Board.

How can I show each discussion in a single Page (Like List View Webpart) and Like, Comment buttons will be available beside each discussion and user don't need to navigate to another page for comment or like.